# OpenCV3.10 - Python 3.5 Axis 216FD IP Security camera - capture video

Tags: python, opencv, .net-3.5

New to opencv3 and python 3.6 64 bit. 
Streaming live video to computer from Axis 216FD  IP security camera.
Authentication completed as to Username and password
Live view URL - http://192.168.1.140/view/viewer_index.shtml'

> Error opening capture device
>
> frame 1 = None
>
> frame is None

The commented out URL information below does not capture any video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi? 
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?
date=1&clock=1&resolution=[WIDTH]X[HEIGHT']
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/jpg/image.jpg')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/SnapshotJPEG?
Resolution=320X240')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/jpg/image.jpg=3')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?
resolution=352X240?.mjpg')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/mjpg/video.mjpg')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('192.168.1.140/view/viewer_index_shtml')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/mjpg/video.mjpg')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/view/viewer_index.shtml')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('192.168.1.140')
#capture = cv2.VideoCapture('192.168.1.140/my/stream.mjpeg')

capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.140/view/viewer_index.shtml')
if not capture.isOpened():
    print ("Error opening capture device")
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if capture.isOpened():
    print ("Device captured correctly",capture)

while 1:

 ret, frame = capture.read()
 print ("frame1 =",frame)

 if ret == False :
  print ("frame is None")
  break

 cv2.imshow('Camera 1',frame)

 if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
  print ('ESC pressed. Exiting ...')
  break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You have to find the actual video URL. Does opening `/mjpg/video.mjpg` in your browser work?

Comment: A lot of unformatted code is not a question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bender -- Thanks for the info  --  Did not work - Error opening capture device
         frame 1 = None
         frame is None

Comment: Bender - Went back to the browser and it did work. It brought up my authentication required. Completed this form and the video started.

Comment: Bender - However in my program it did not bring up this authentication requirement.  Everything should work well if my program brought up this page.  How do we do this?